# How to close side-nav after someone clicks a link?

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm using Materialize and for some reason the side-nav on small screen sizes doesn't close after the user clicks on a link. Test site is https://www.renteria.me

Answer (score 0):

That is happening because the link is on the same page. You are going to have to trigger the link to close after a user clicks on it.

One way you can do it is trigger a javascript function like this (everytime someone clicks the link):

Add this in the link after href and class:

```
onclick="myFunction()"
```

at this at the bottom of the page:

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("sidenav");
        x.style.display = "none";
}
```

Without testing this I am not 100% sure it is fully functional but this should at least get you started on the right path

Answer (score 0):

The sidenav doesn't close as the client is not redirected to a new page. You need to call the `close` method of the sidenav as a user clicks on a anchor link in the sidenav:

```
instance.close();
```

A full example would be as follows:

```
var elem = $('.sidenav');
var instance = M.Sidenav.getInstance(elem);

$('.sidenav a').click(function() {
    instance.close();
});
```